# Jquery ajax script doesn't change div content if ajax returns nothing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am wondering how i can change this jQuery Ajax script so it doesn't change the div content if the Ajax returns nothing? I'm pretty new to jQuery & JavaScript sorry. Thanks :)

Source code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#load_tweets').load('record_count.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds

<body>
<div id="load_tweets"> </div>
</body>

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function:

```
$('#load_tweets').load('record_count.php').fadeIn("slow");
```

Try [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'record_count.php',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(result) {
        if (result != null && result != '') {
            $('#load_tweets').html(result).fadeIn('slow');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the ajax jquery version to get more control on your request.
You can see the response data and see if it has data.

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function(){
  $.ajax({
       url: "record_count.php",
       success: function(data){
              if(jQuery.trim(data) != ""){
                 $('#load_tweets').html(data);
              }
          },
       dataType: 'html'
  });
}, 10000);
```